# Network routing and port forwarding problem

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, port-forwarding, nat

I have 2 networks (graph in link below)

A: 10.0.0.0/24

B: 192.168.1.0/24

In network A, all devices are connected via a switch. Some devices provide certain services such as ssh or access to a database server.

Compter (PC1) has an Ubuntu 20 operating system. I'd like to stay with that system.

Computer on network A (PC1) can connect to network B via Wi-Fi and with network A via ethernet. **I would like to be able to access some services (from network A) from network B through one address on specific ports.** The rest of the services from network should not be available.

My attempts to use DNAT and SNAT have failed. I had access to the computer that was setting nat but other devices were not receiving packets

'Port forwarding is enabled'

PC1 has address :

A) 172.17.10.2

B) 192.168.1.196

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.196 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.10.2`

`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.10.2 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.196`

I think i should use gateway for network A that is routed to network B but i do not have any idea how to achieve this goal.

[network graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz2r0.png)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I am not sure I understand the situation correctly, but you can't use Grobal IP and Local IP at the same time. You can probably connect A and B directly via COM or such ports and it will be a new network or a new hardware protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to accomplish is have PC1, which is running Ubuntu, provide DNAT (Destination address and port change) for IP traffic from clients on network B to some specific servers on network A, and you wish to map the services from these servers to specific ports on the network B IP address of PC1.   You don't however want to do generic NAT routing between network A to B or vis versa, and no traffic for the internet needs to pass between A and B.

This is basically called "Port Forwarding" or DNAT, which is one of the functions provided by a generic home NAT router that would sit between your ISP (single public IP address) and your private local network.  But your application doesn't want the other typical feature of a home NAT router like DHCP server or upstream NAT to the internet.

You are on the right track to use iptables firewall rules and enable packet forwarding.  Directly configuring [iptables is complex to understand](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo), but your need is fairly simple.  Unfortunately, I don't have a DNAT recipe for iptables for your application, but I'd look for details on the following.  First you need a rule to perform the DNAT mapping from PC1 Network B:portX to Server on Network A:portY for each service you are trying to forward and it must include the ports number being used on both sides, and second rule is needed for the reverse direction traffic back from Network A servers that relies on state from the first rule (I believe these are two separate rules in iptables). Your example DNAT rule needs to be modified so that the DNAT destination is the Server IP address on network A, not the PC1 network A IP address.  Finally you need rules to override any default DROP rules that would normally prevent traffic from B to reach A, but only for traffic headed for your specific services you want open to network B and sourced locally on network B.

Rather than writing iptables rules directly, I have had good luck with firewall rule generation programs like [Firewall Builder (graphical input)](http://fwbuilder.sourceforge.net/4.0/quick_start_guide.shtml) and [FireHOL (text-based input)](https://firehol.org/guides/firehol-welcome/), which can help you build and maintain very complicated Firewall and NAT routing rules.

I hope this helps you find a solution.